# Block displaying in 'content' region of admin theme?

Tags: blocks

The below implementation of `hook_block_info` renders a block in the 'content' region of my theme. Unfortunately, it also appears in the content region of the administrative theme. The [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) states:

> properties: (optional) Array of additional metadata to add to the
>   block. Common properties include: administrative:
>
> Boolean that
>   categorizes this block as usable in an administrative context. This
>   might include blocks that help an administrator approve/deny comments,
>   or view recently created user accounts.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['diary'] = array(
    'info' => t('Diary'),
    'properties' => array('administrative' => FALSE),
    'weight' => 1,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'region' => 'content',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

However, my block is still appearing in the 'content' region of the administrative theme?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/49328#comment-49328), you can also specify the theme. I haven't tried it -- let us know if it works!

> There's also a theme key-value pair:

```
'exposed_order' => array(
'info' => t('Exposed commerce order filter'),
'theme' => $admin_theme,
'region' => 'content',
'pages' => ORDER_MENU_LINK,
'status' => 1,
'visibility' => 1,
),
```

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this, but I would have to specify just my current theme, which means if I switch themes the problem would return.

Comment: Can you go into the block configuration and just turn it off for the administrative theme in the settings page?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of workarounds, but I want to know how the properties attributes work.

Comment: No problem -- I suggested a slight edit to your question to clarify that you are mainly interested in further info about the properties attribute.